# Why the use of "default" keyword in java8

Tags: java, java-8, interface, default

In Java 8 `default` method implementation is introduced. My question is why the need to have `default` keyword in the method name/signature. Why can't it be without the `default` keyword just like a usual method implementation?

Comment: I assume you mean default implementations of interface methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It makes the intention clear. You can't *accidentally* create a default implementation for a method. Just like `abstract` methods require the keyword, instead of just being methods without implementation.

A safety precaution for the careless programmers.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that since Java 8 interfaces also support `static` methods. Leaving out the `default` keyword opens the door to ambiguity: would a method declaration in an interface that has no modifier be *implicitly static* (like constants), or *implicitly default*? As it is, everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is speculation, but educated speculation. What @Kayaman's answer says is also likely true.

Java aims to be as backward compatible as possible. If you didn't include the default keyword then potentially invalid code, perhaps written by mistake, in a previous java version now compiles on Java 8+. This can be viewed as breaking backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -4):

In Java 8, “Default Method” or (Defender methods) feature, which allows the developer to add new methods to the interfaces without breaking their existing implementation. It provides the flexibility to allow interface to define implementation which will use as the default in a situation where a concrete class fails to provide an implementation for that method.

You can refer the below URL to understand more details.
https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java

Comment: The question wasn't about what the default keyword was, but about why it is needed.